# Unable to parse JSON string with highcharts exporting server with the windows phantomjs version

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, export, phantomjs

What i did:

- Download the latest phantomjs (1.9.2, windows)
- Download the latest sources of highcharts-convert.js from github (note: download the whole directory)
- Start phantomjs with convert script in server mode:

`bin\phantomjs.exe --debug=yes js\highcharts-convert.js -host 127.0.0.1 -port 3003`

- Use CURL to send example json to phantomjs server:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"infile":"{xAxis: {categories: [\"Jan\", \"Feb\", \"Mar\"]},series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]}"}' 127.0.0.1:3003`

What I got:

`Failed rendering:
SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string`

Note: This is running fine on the command line:

`bin\phantomjs js\highcharts-convert.js -infile options.json -outfile chart.svg`

Comment: Hi! I reproduced your steps on W8. Copy and paste your commands and it's working out of the box... Is it still not working?

Comment: I got the same problem on Win7 Pro. I use phantomjs 1.9.7.