# Highcharts - parsing error generating image with phantomjs web server

Tags: json, highcharts, export, phantomjs

I have exactly the same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919824/unable-to-parse-json-string-with-highcharts-exporting-server-with-the-windows-ph) (I reiterate the question as it hasn't been resolved). I downloaded the latest version of highcharts-convert.js and all other *.js scripts from github. Tried several JSON variations of infile and always get the same error: Unable to parse JSON string. It works fine from command line but doesn't on phantomjs as web server. Can you please advise how to fix this problem. Thanks.

UPDATE:

This is the content of the options file that works from the command line:

```
{

        xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

        }]
};
```

And this is the curl command that returns the error:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"infile":"{xAxis: {categories: [\"Jan\", \"Feb\", \"Mar\"]},series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]}"}' 127.0.0.1:3003
```

I'm not sure it matters, but I'm running phantomjs.exe on Windows 7 64bit

Comment: Could you attach options file for that chart? Also, paste here full command you are using.

Comment: Pawel, thanks for your replay, please see the update.

Comment: Your JSON isn't correct. Try to put options from infile and test it here: http://jsonlint.com/ For example: change xAxis -> "xAxis".

Comment: Thanks. I know it's not a valid JSON, but I took the sample from highcharts.com http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside
I validated successfully the following in jsonlint.com:
{"xAxis":{"categories":["Jan","Feb","Mar"]},"series":[{"data":[29.9,71.5,106.4]}]}
and run the command below but I still get the same error 'Unable to parse JSON string':
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"infile":"{\"xAxis\":{\"categories\":[\"Jan\",\"Feb\",\"Mar\"]},\"series\":[{\"data\":[29.9,71.5,106.4]}]} "}' 127.0.0.1:3003

Comment: I also tried: curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"infile":"{"xAxis":{"categories":["Jan","Feb","Mar"]},"series":[{​"data":[29.9,71.5,106.4]}]} "}' 127.0.0.1:3003   without escaping quotes and got a similar error

Comment: It's very interesting.. I have tried to validate any of your examples, and all of them are not validating properly. Could you open JS console in your browser and try to encode JSON using: `JSON.parse('some JSON ')`, like this one: `JSON.parse(' {"xAxis":{"categories":["Jan","Feb","Mar"]},"series":[{"data":[29.9,71.5,106.4]}‌​]}  ');`. I get error in console.

Comment: the JSON below parses correctly, there were some hidden characters I had to delete. Do you have a curl example that works with phantomjs/highcharts web server? I'm confused whether to use JSON or javascript objects in infile. thanks

JSON.parse ('{"xAxis":{"categories":["Jan","Feb","Mar"]},"series":[{"data":[29.9,71.5,106.4]}]}')